# Call,apply in js

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to JS and can't understand why there is no argument needed for l function, but at the same time necessary for f function. Is it somehow connected with differences between usages of call and apply?

```
function f(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
    console.log(this);
}

f('abc');             

f.call('123', 'abc');


function l() {
    console.log(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i])
    }
}

l(1, 2, 3);                   

l.apply('abc', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Comment: _"[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is an Array-like object accessible inside functions that contains the values of the arguments passed to that function."_

Comment: thanks for the answer, got it!